# Phpmyadmin shows "No tables found in database." but tables still exist on the left sidebar?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm having a very weird problem right now, I reinstalled Wamp server (same version, same folder, everything is the same). But after I reinstalled it, my database got damaged. It shows that I don't have tables in my database even though the tables still show when I open my database on the left sidebar. Trying to exporting and importing the database only creates an empty database. I sadly didn't create a backup because I reinstalled wamp multiple times before without it damaging any fields or databases.

Here's a screenshot (My database's name is asd) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyp3E.png

Is there any way to repair this database ?

Comment: Are you expecting your database to still exist after re-installing MySql? Do need to re-create your database, and/or tables?

Comment: Well, I uninstalled and installed Wamp because I have a weird bug on my computer but that's another topic. Now, I did that multiple times already and it worked just fine without hurting any of my databases but this time it destroyed my Database for some reason.

Comment: Was there something different about the final re-install?

Comment: No, I installed the same version with the same settings. I changed nothing and it usually works fine.

Comment: The install will have put a vanilla version of the `mysql` database onto your system. Thats the database MySQL uses to record databases/user/tables etc. So its a bit like replacing the registry in windows. Files may still be there but MySQL has no knowledge of them.

Comment: If this is an INNODB database using `innodb_file_per_table=1` as I assume you have. You would still require the `.FRM` files and the `ibdata1` to all match for that database to work as eveen if you are using File-Per_Table a id is still kept in the ibdata1 file for each table that is stored seperately. The install would probably have overwritten the ibdata1 file at least. **Still just goes to prove a BACKUP is worth a 1000 questions**

Comment: Here is an article on [recovering a INNODB database if you only have the `.idb` files](http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/). Its **FAR FROM STRAIGHT FORWARD** and you will need to know the exact table definition for each table you are trying to recover!

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had that, I had to change ownership. This is how I did it in Linux.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

In windows you can right-click the mysql database folder, in you case

`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\asd`

And then go to Security Make sure all permissions are OK.

[image]

Then you can go to Advanced > Owner and make sure ownership,

[image]

Comment: Is this due to re-installing with different Users? Or to do with reclaiming an existing service?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it did not work. Any other possible fixes ?

Comment: To be totally honest, I am not 100% sure but my database folder was root:root instead mysql:mysql

Comment: @wamp do you see your folder? `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\asd`

Comment: The folder is a bit different in Wamp but yes I do see it at : C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\asd

Comment: you right, I am updating the path. if there is no sensitive information can you please attach the data folder. I will try to replicate your issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to attach my folder here on Stack overflow. By the way, I tried to drop my database and it showed me this error message : http://i.imgur.com/ZZklulo.png   I will attach the folder asap once I figure out how to actually do it haha.

Comment: you are getting the error becuase it failed to delete the folder asd. `rmdir` is the command for deleting a folder. I insist, this should be a permission/ownership issue.  Is your account an administrator?

Comment: Yep, it is an administrator, I do not have any other accounts on my computer. It shouldn't be a permission/owenership issue because I gave myself full permisions to the folder. Here's the link for the files btw, just ctrl+a and you can download them, sorry I didn't find another option: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jm7b3wra2bp9gab/AADtZQEOzHZo1Aj1eF3f5cF6a?dl=0

Comment: If I am not mistaking, your tables are InnoDB. If this is the case, mysql website has a documentation of how to backup innoDB tables. however; they said you should have some `frm` files which I don't see in your dropbox Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html

Comment: Permission **are almost never the issue** on a windows system.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i am kind of with you; however; the error he is getting trying to drop the table, make me wonder.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i am kind of with you; however; the error he is getting trying to drop the table makes me wonder. In the other hand, the data files that he shared is incomplete or something. Based on mysql documentation, he should have some frm files.

Comment: I expect he either forgot to copy the `.frm` files or has deleted them, also the `ibdata1` file would also be required as an ID number of each table is kept in there for each file-per-table and if they dont match its a nightmare. The install would probably have overwritten the `ibdata1` file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and all I had to do was restart the database.